# Execute code when while statement is true, of not user must type in a new input

Tags: java, while-loop

Hello (I'm new to Java and programming). I'm trying to make a while loop . If the user has typed in an integer, execute the code. If the user has not typed in an integer, the user has to type an input untill the input is true.

I tried to do it like this:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Wat is jouw gewicht in kg op aarde?");
        int gewicht = input.nextInt();

        while (input.hasNextInt ()) {

            System.out.println("Ik heb informatie over de volgende planeten: 1. Venus  2. Mars 3. Jupiter \n 4. Saturn 5. Uranus 6. Neptune");

            //Vraag op welke planeet hij wilt boxen
            System.out.println("Op welk planeet ga je boksen?");
            int planeetnummer = input.nextInt();

            if (planeetnummer == VENUS) {
                System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Venus is: " + gewicht * 0.78 + " kg");
            }

            if (planeetnummer == MARS) {
                System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Mars is: " + gewicht * 0.39 + " kg");
            }

            if (planeetnummer == JUPITER) {
                System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Jupiter is: " + gewicht * 2.65 + " kg");
            }
            if (planeetnummer == SATURN) {
                System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Saturn is: " + gewicht * 1.17 + " kg");
            }
            if (planeetnummer == URANUS) {
                System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Uranus is: " + gewicht * 1.05 + " kg");
            }
            if (planeetnummer == NEPTUNE) {
                System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Neptune is: " + gewicht * 1.23 + " kg");
            }
        }
```

So yeh if the user types in an integer it should execute the code and if not the user has to type another input untill its an integer.
But when I run my code and I type an integer the code is not excecuting and I don't know why? Can anyone help me so this while loop will work?

Comment: what is the VENUS or others ? Enum or whatelse ?

Comment: These should be `int` constants to be comparable by `==`. But let us see what OP will say.

Comment: They are final ints, but that doesn't matter I just want to execute that code if the user has typed an input. How can I do that?

Comment: input int i mean

Comment: I suggest that you write a function `int getInput()` or something similar. This will help you focus on the single task that you want. Now you can figure out how to detect if the user doesn't type a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

You have to press the 'Enter' button after writing a number - this is how you notify the program to read the input.

### Edit

Here is a code that will show an error message if the user will type in a letter.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Wat is jouw gewicht in kg op aarde?");
    int gewicht = 0;
    try {
        gewicht = new Integer(input.next());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("please enter an integer");
    }
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        int planeetnummer = 0;
        try {
            planeetnummer = new Integer(input.next());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("please enter an integer");
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("Ik heb informatie over de volgende planeten: 1. Venus  2. Mars 3. Jupiter \n 4. Saturn 5. Uranus 6. Neptune");

        //Vraag op welke planeet hij wilt boxen
        System.out.println("Op welk planeet ga je boksen?");
        switch (planeetnummer) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Venus is: " + gewicht * 0.78 + " kg");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Mars is: " + gewicht * 0.39 + " kg");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Jupiter is: " + gewicht * 2.65 + " kg");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Saturn is: " + gewicht * 1.17 + " kg");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Uranus is: " + gewicht * 1.05 + " kg");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Neptune is: " + gewicht * 1.23 + " kg");
            break;
        }
    }
   input.close();
```

Comment: I believe that frodo wants to handle invalid input such as letters when the app only works with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I added some comment your code to understand. So analyze this ;

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Wat is jouw gewicht in kg op aarde?");
int gewicht;

//while weight is integer
while (true) {
    try {
        gewicht = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.print("Try again: ");
    }
}

//add break for ending this while loop !!!!!!!!!
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Ik heb informatie over de volgende planeten: 1. Venus  2. Mars 3. Jupiter \n 4. Saturn 5. Uranus 6. Neptune");

    //Vraag op welke planeet hij wilt boxen
    System.out.println("Op welk planeet ga je boksen?");
    int planeetnummer;

    //while input is integer
    while (true) {
        try {
            planeetnummer = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.print("Try again: ");
        }
    }

    if (planeetnummer == VENUS) {
        System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Venus is: " + gewicht * 0.78 + " kg");
    }

    if (planeetnummer == MARS) {
        System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Mars is: " + gewicht * 0.39 + " kg");
    }

    if (planeetnummer == JUPITER) {
        System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Jupiter is: " + gewicht * 2.65 + " kg");
    }
    if (planeetnummer == SATURN) {
        System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Saturn is: " + gewicht * 1.17 + " kg");
    }
    if (planeetnummer == URANUS) {
        System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Uranus is: " + gewicht * 1.05 + " kg");
    }
    if (planeetnummer == NEPTUNE) {
        System.out.println("Jou gewicht op Neptune is: " + gewicht * 1.23 + " kg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an `Enum` with planets' properties:

```
enum Planet {
    VENUS(1, "Venus", 0.78),
    MARS(2, "Mars", 0.39),
    JUPITER(3, "Jupiter", 2.64),
    SATURN(4, "Saturn", 1.17),
    URANUS(5, "Uranus", 1.05),
    NEPTUNE(6, "Neptune", 1.23);

    private final int number;
    private final String name;
    private final double gravity;

    Planet(int number, String name, double gravity) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.gravity = gravity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getGravity() {
        return gravity;
    }

    public static Planet parseNumber(int number) {
        for (Planet planet : values())
            if (planet.number == number)
                return planet;
        throw new EnumConstantNotPresentException(Planet.class, String.valueOf(number));
    }
}
```

And then your client code could look like this one:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Wat is jouw gewicht in kg op aarde?");
        int gewicht = input.nextInt();

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Ik heb informatie over de volgende planeten: 1. Venus  2. Mars 3. Jupiter");
            System.out.println("4. Saturn 5. Uranus 6. Neptune");
            System.out.println("Op welk planeet ga je boksen?");

            Planet planet = Planet.parseNumber(input.nextInt());
            System.out.format("Jou gewicht op %s is: %f kg\n", planet.getName(), gewicht * planet.getGravity());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is not being executed cause `while(input.hasNextInt())` loop will be executed only if the user types an int, otherwise your program will end.

Try to use the follwing code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
  if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
    int input = sc.nextInt();
    // your code goes here
  } else {
    sc.next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use recusion

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    inputNumber();
}

public static void inputNumber() {
    Integer number = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("type number");
        number = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        inputNumber();
    }
    //execute code
}
```

Comment: If the user types in bad input often enough, the program will crash.